# Missing Characters From LOAD DATA INFILE command in MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm using a LOAD DATA function to import a csv file into a MySQL; however, I noticed some of the values in the first column are partially populated. The LOAD DATA function didn't return any warnings, which leads me to think this is an issue with the terminal display, rather than a problem with the command itself. If you have any input I'd greatly appreciate some guidance!

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Tvv.jpg)
[LOAD DATA function top left, CSV top right, SELECT * function bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H97pt.jpg)

Comment: The csv file only appears to contain 1 column?

Comment: I redacted the other columns for this post

Comment: In that case my guess would be ‘\r\n’